# webscrypt only one part of the a class?

Tags: python, web-scraping, data-mining

I am new to webscrypt I just build a webscrypt but i have an issue with the part I want to get!

When I run my script it give me `Voir l’information détaillée de Queco Electric Ltd` but I only want to get `Queco Electric Ltd`
See code bellow to understand! Thanks you for the help guys!

webscript.py

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


def test():
    url = 'https://www.pagesjaunes.ca/search/si/1/electricien/Montreal+QC'
    r = requests.get(url)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text)

    name = soup.find_all("a",{"class":"listing__name--link listing__link jsListingName"})
    for i in name:
        names = i.get("title")
        print(names)
test()
```

print result:

```
Voir l’information détaillée de Les Entreprises Electriques G P E Inc
Voir l’information détaillée de Michel Guimont Entrepreneur Electricien Ltée
Voir l’information détaillée de PGR Électrique Inc
Voir l’information détaillée de Queco Electric Ltd
Voir l’information détaillée de Construction Hydro Métropolitain
```

DOC
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This code

````
import requests


def test():
    url = 'https://www.pagesjaunes.ca/search/si/1/electricien/Montreal+QC'
    r = requests.get(url)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text)

name=soup.find_all("a",{"class":"listing__name--link listing__link jsListingName"})
    for i in name:
        # phone=i.a.get("data-phone")
        name=i.text
        print(name) ```
````

Comment: Worked! Thankl you sir!

Answer (score 0):

Change your soup with this and also for loop...

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


def test():
    url = 'https://www.pagesjaunes.ca/search/si/1/electricien/Montreal+QC'
    r = requests.get(url)
    # change this
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')

    name=soup.find_all("a", {"class":"listing__name--link listing__link jsListingName"})
    for i in name:
        # change this
        name = i.text
        print(name)
test()
```